# Archive rows from different sheets and remove them to initial position (to initial sheet) when I want to unarchive (google sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have 4 sheets in the same spreadsheet: 3 per employee (Elisa, Miriam, Victor) and 1 for archive (Archive). When a project is done, each employee can archive the entire row -thanks to the following script- through a checkbox (data validation).
This row is removed to the sheet called "Archive".

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 2 or B
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Elisa" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Archive" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Elisa");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

I saved this script which is working under "Archive - Elisa" in the script editor.

I am facing 2 issues. 
**First**, I duplicated this script for the other employees and I saved each script under "Archive - NameEmployee" in the script editor. When I run the scripts, it doesn't work for Miriam or Victor: so if I check a box in Miriam's or Victor's sheet, the row doesn't move to Archive. This is just working for Elisa. **Second**, I am desperate because I cannot find the way to remove the row from Archive to its initial sheet. What I would like is: when Victor is unchecking the box from Archive, the row is going back to its sheet, and not to Miriam's or Elisa's.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First: If you want the same script to run for Miriam and Victor - you do not need to make a copies of the script.

More precisely, you should not do it, because this will lead to having three `onEdit` functions in the same project which is not allowed.

Also, copying the script and saving it under the other employes' names will not make it work for them.

Instead, you need to modify the script.

The line

`if(s.getName() == "Elisa" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) {`

specifies that the row shall only be archived if the sheet name is "Elisa". To make it work for the other employees modify it to:

`if((s.getName() == "Elisa"||s.getName() == "Victor"||s.getName() == "Miriam" )&& r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) {`

### Second:

The line `var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Elisa");` specifies that the sheet to which the row shall be moved back is "Elisa".

If you want it to move to the sheet of the person who created this row - this row must have some information about its creator. Does it have some? If not, you must implement an additional column in all sheets that specify the creator.

If the creator name is stored in column S, you can change the `else` statement of your code as following:

```
else if(s.getName() == "Archive" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var nameColumn = 19;
    var name = s.getRange(row, nameColumn).getValue();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
```

Basically, you retrieve the name of the row creator with

`var name = s.getRange(row, nameColumn).getValue();`

and then pass the content of the variable to

`var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);`.

Thus, the targetsheet will be established dynamically, depending on the row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the first issue is solved thanks to you!

Comment: On the 2nd, for each row, in column S, the employee is identified!

Comment: And the name in column S is exaclty the same like the sheet names? "Elisa", "Miriam" and "Victor"?

Comment: Yes, it is a column that identifies the owner of the sheet and the employee then

Comment: Thank you for your help, really. Finally the name is in W (so I updated var nameColumn = 22) and the name in W is exactly the same name for the sheets.
But I am probably missing something because it doesn't work from my side...

Comment: What exactly does not work? Did you delete the spare copies of the script?

Comment: Yes I replaced the else statement of my code by yours. So the archiving is working; but when I uncheck the box, the row isn't going back to the owner's sheet :(

Comment: I can have a look at it if you share a copy of your spreadsheet with me.

Comment: Btw., W corresponds to 23, not 22 - this might be the error source.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRyyE-oNQ1cwN4yua4_0sWUzfByK2BTYOHb2v2bTfCM/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the file :) Thank you for your help again. And I don't know if you know how to do, but every time I was unchecking the box (only with Elisa sheet), the row was being removed to the end of the table because of the checkbox... So I tried to create a function saying that if clients (col C) wasn't filled; there shouldn't have been the checkbox, but that was undoing the all script. All of this is new for me.

Comment: You need to make the file shareable.

Comment: I just had a look -three things: 1. As mentioned `W` is column `23`, not `22`. Second: a small mistake in my code: It should be `var name = s.getRange(row, nameColumn).getValue();`, not `column` . 3.  The easiest thing to do is to jsut manually remove all empty rows from all sheets. Hope it helps!

Comment: It is perfect, thank you so much! Have a great day :)